How does ASP.NET Core generate TOTP (Time-Based One-Time Password) for 2FA?
I am trying to understand how ASP.NET generates the TOTP (Time-Based One-Time Password) when requested.
Looking at Rfc6238AuthenticationService implementation, I can see that each token should expire after 3 minutes by default. However, if I generate a token and attempt to validate it after 4 minutes the token is accepted. I expect that the token will not work after the expiration time.
When looking at the code on line 111 I see the following comment

Allow a variance of no greater than 9 minutes in either direction

Where is 9 coming from here? And why would we allow variance of no greater than 9 minutes in either direction?
But then on line 119 it seems to be looping from -2 to 2 which calculates tokens from (currentTimeStep -2) to (currentTimeStep +2) so that is 5 different tokens but not 9.
Questions

Where does the value 9 in the comment comes from and what is special about 9 here?
ThecurrentTimeStep variable seems to be in ticks so adding 2 means adding 2 ticks not minutes. Why does the comment state 9 minutes?


It's allowing two steps in either direction according to the RFC https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6238#section-5.2 the comment assumes the step is 3 minutes, based on private static readonly TimeSpan _timestep = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3); the function GetCurrentTimeStepNumber calculates the step number based on that. The comment isn't 100% accurate: it's actually this step (anywhere in the 3 minutes) and up to 6 more minutes, so it could be a total of 9 minutes off in some cases but not others.
